# Entity Framework 4: Mapping several assocation tables to entities

Tags: database, entity-framework-4, mapping

I am kind of new to Entity Framework and ORMs.  I have a simple database schema that is kind of like this.

```
User:
   Id
   Name

Group:
   Id
   Name

Role:
   Id
   Name
```

There are many-many between groups and users.  Also, there is many-many between users and roles.  However, Roles are per group. So we could have the following:

User A belongs to Group 1 with Roles a,b,c and belongs to Group 2, but has Roles d,e,f.

So we have some association tables like so:

```
UserRoles:
   UserId -> User.Id
   RoleId -> Role.Id

UserGroups
   UserId -> User.Id
   GroupId -> Group.Id

GroupRoles:
   GroupId -> Group.Id
   RoleId -> Role.Id
```

So, in my entities I want to have a Role entitiy, a User entity with a collection of Roles and a Group entity with a collection of Users and a collection of Roles.

When I load a group, I want to only load the users in that group and only that users roles for that group.

So my question:
In the above example.  How do I make it so when I load Group 1, I want to see User A with Roles a,b,c and NOT Roles d,e,f.

Thanks,
JR

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call something like Group.User.Roles to get all Roles the user belongs to in the Group. something like:

```
var group1 = objectContext.Groups.Where(x => x.GroupId == 1);
var userARoles = group1.Users.Where(x => x.UserId == "A").Roles;
```

Does this help you?

Comment: Will test this out and let you know.  Thanks.

Comment: This returns all of the roles for userA, regardless of the group they belong to.  I have to intersect the roles for userA with the roles for group1 to get the set I want.  Thanks.